# I want only Name of engineers from the engineer table

Tags: django

**it is the out put after the print enigeer,here i want only name of engineer sachin,rahul,altaf**

```
        [<Engineer: Sachin>, <Engineer: Rahul>, <Engineer: Altaf>]


def enginer(request):

    engineer=Engineer.objects.all()
    print engineer
```

Answer (score 3):

An even more concise way to retrieve only the names is to use a flat list by passing `flat=True` to the `values_list` function:

```
Engineer.objects.values_list('name', flat=True)
```

And this will return:

```
[u'Sachin', u'Rahul', u'Altaf']
```

You can only use `flat=True` if you're retrieving a single column.

However, if you still want to use the engineer objects down the road, you'd be better of constructing a list using list comprehension:

```
>>> engineers = Engineer.objects.all()
>>> names = [x.name for x in engineers]
>>> print names
[u'Sachin', u'Rahul', u'Altaf']
>>> for engineer in engineers:
...     do_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it that way:

```
engineer=Engineer.objects.values('name').all()
```

Answer (score 0):

If all that you want is names, you can use `values_list()`:

```
Engineer.objects.values_list('name')
```

this will return something like:

```
[(u'Name1', ), (u'Name2', )]
```

Differently from `values()` which returns a list of dictionaries, `values_list()` returns a list of tuples, and as far I know is the most simple and concise way to retrieve labels only.